# InteractiveViewer does not hide other Widgets when panned

Tags: flutter

I used InteractiveViewer here on my ProductDetail Page.

[image]

But when I pan and Zoom the image, the other widgets such as buttons and text are coming over it.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class ProductDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  ProductDetail({this.product});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -20,
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                child: Hero(
                    tag: product.id,
                    child: Carousel(
                        autoplay: false,
                        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                        dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                        dotColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        images: [
                          AssetImage(product.imageUrl),
                          AssetImage(product.imageUrl),
                          AssetImage(product.imageUrl),
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -20,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '₹ ${product.price}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '₹ ${product.price}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                            color: Colors.grey
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(getColorFromHex('#d1d1d1')),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                            Text("Add to Cart", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(getColorFromHex('#56a8e2')),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
                          Text("Buy Now", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I hide the other widgets like Text and buttons when I pan or zoom the image with the InteractiveViewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. InteractiveViewer has two properties onInteractionStart and onInteractionEnd.

> onInteractionStart → void Function(ScaleStartDetails details) : Called
> when the user begins a pan or scale gesture on the widget.
>
> onInteractionEnd → void Function(ScaleEndDetails details) : Called
> when the user ends a pan or scale gesture on the widget.

2. You need to wrap the widgets that you wish to hide with the Visibility widget.
3. You can set - reset the visibility of the widgets wrapped under Visibility widget when user starts (onInteractionStart) and stops to pan or scale (onInteractionEnd).

Please see the code below, I had to make some changes to make it work :

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ProductDetail(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  ProductDetail({products});

  @override
  _ProductDetailState createState() => _ProductDetailState();
}

class _ProductDetailState extends State<ProductDetail> {
  bool _visible = true;
  TransformationController controller = TransformationController();

  final Products products = Products(
      id: 10,
      imageUrl:
          "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/01/17/11/temple-5619197_960_720.jpg",
      price: 20.00);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                transformationController: controller,
                onInteractionStart: (scale) {
                  setState(() => _visible = false);
                },
                onInteractionEnd: (scale) {
                  setState(() {
                     controller.value = Matrix4.identity();
                     _visible = true;
                  });
                },
                child: Hero(
                  tag: products.id,
                  child: Carousel(
                    autoplay: false,
                    boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                    dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                    dotColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    images: [
                      NetworkImage(products.imageUrl),
                      NetworkImage(products.imageUrl),
                      NetworkImage(products.imageUrl),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _visible,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '₹ ${products.price.toString()}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '₹ ${products.price.toString()}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _visible,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.cyanAccent),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                          Text("Add to Cart", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.limeAccent),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
                          Text("Buy Now", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Products {
  final int id;
  final String imageUrl;
  final double price;
  Products({
    this.id,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.price,
  });

  Products copyWith({
    int id,
    String imageUrl,
    double price,
  }) {
    return Products(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      imageUrl: imageUrl ?? this.imageUrl,
      price: price ?? this.price,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort, thanks a lot! This does solve my problem, but only to a certain extent. After zooming, when I leave screen touch, the buttons and other widgets appear again. Do you have a solution to that?

Comment: The visibility is set to false when user interaction starts and reset back to true when user interaction ends. If you do not want the buttons and widgets to become visible again then do not add the following code : 

                onInteractionEnd: (scale) {
                  setState(() {
                    setState(() => _visible = true);
                  });
                },

Comment: When the image is zoomed in and then user leaves the screen touch, and the image is not zoomed out, the widgets reappear on the (zoomed) image...

Comment: I've updated the code. Now when the user leaves the screen the image is reset back to original size and the buttons become visible again. The image size is reset by setting the controller.value = Matrix4.identity();